# How to mock an api call and library in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have code that looks like this:

```
# Create SQS client
sqs = boto3.client(
    'sqs',
    region_name='us-west-2',
    aws_access_key_id= <some key>,
    aws_secret_access_key= sdcFunctions.pipelineParameters()['sqs_secret_access_key']
)

queue_url = sdcFunctions.pipelineParameters()['sqs_queue_url']

for record in records:
  try:
    message_body = {
      "assertion": build_assertion()
    }

    response = sqs.send_message(
      QueueUrl=queue_url,
      MessageAttributes={

      },
      MessageBody=(
        json.dumps(message_body)
      ),
      MessageDeduplicationId= str(record.value['message_composite_key']), 
      MessageGroupId='someId'
    )
```

I want to basically mock out this: `sqs.send_message` and test that `send_message` was called with the right parameters. How do I do this?

Comment: You have mock's [`assert_called_with`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_with)

Answer (score 0):

Simply overwrite the method - python is of the opinion that you are an adult and co everything you want, including shooting your foot off because you are reckless.

```
def intercepter(**kwargs);
    pass
    // do something here to validate your args
sqs.send_message = interceptor
```

There are facilities in pytests mock fixture to automatically restore the method you mock. You should probably use these.